# simplexml stuck parsing xml

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to parse an xml file, I can get the d3pp1:key and d3p1:values alright.

```
foreach ($xml_contact->Attributes->KeyValuePairOfstringanyType as $node) {
    $key = (string)$node->children('d3p1', TRUE)->key;
    $value = (string)$node->children('d3p1', TRUE)->value;

    do_stuff($key, $value);
}
```

But i also need to get this 9ccaa69b-fced-e411-80da-00155d0a0806
and I am struggling to figure out how to reference it.

I have tried various incarnations along these lines

```
$node->children('d3p1', TRUE)->value->Id
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  <d3p1:key>birthdate</d3p1:key>
  <d3p1:value xmlns:d5p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d5p1:dateTime">1940-12-10T11:00:00Z</d3p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  <d3p1:key>parentcustomerid</d3p1:key>
  <d3p1:value i:type="EntityReference">
    <Id>9ccaa69b-fced-e411-80da-00155d0a0806</Id>
    <KeyAttributes xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts"/>
    <LogicalName>account</LogicalName>
    <Name>Test ABC</Name>
    <RowVersion i:nil="true"/>
  </d3p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```

Comment: you may need to do a registerXPathNamespace on the xml object?

Comment: The XML snippet you show has two root elements. Is that just a part of it or the whole thing? If it's the whole thing, it's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The `Id` element has no namespace prefix, so is in the default namespace of the document, or in no namespace if the document has no default namespace. You need to call `->children()` again to switch to the right namespace, as SimpleXML is currently looking for further nodes in the namespace with prefix `d3p1`.

If there is no default namespace, you just need to pass `NULL`:

```
$node->children('d3p1', TRUE)->value->children(NULL)->Id
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try value->children() but without the null arg, that works great now